# pytest coverage output is cut

Tags: pytest, code-coverage

Running pytest with coverage in a larger project, the output is strangely cut (note the `datam` at the end, many files are still missed here).

*I'm not aware of further configuration—no `pytest.ini`, no `pyproject.toml`, no related environment variable.*

How can I overcome this, given I want the simple terminal output, not an extra report?

*Only if needed:* How could I print the results written to `.coverage` sqlite database to terminal?

```bash
    > pytest tests/ --cov
    ...
    ---------- coverage: platform win32, python 3.10.4-final-0 -----------
    Name                                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
    datamodel\model\gis\topology\edge.py                            26      3    88%
    datamodel\model\gis\version.py                                   0      0   100%
    datam
    ============================== 45 passed in 6.44s ==============================
```

Comment: Without knowing your setup (project, environment, etc) this is impossible to answer.

Comment: `Python version: 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]; pytest==7.1.2; pytest-cov==3.0.0;`
...run in a standard venv: `py -m venv foo`.

Unfortunately cannot reproduce such with other projects yet; the one where this happens is not open source.

Comment: Run `coverage report` after running pytest. You will get the complete report.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug of the `coverage` package, maybe from too many files (>400 in my case), maybe interference with `pytest-xdist`.

In such a case ignore the pytest output and print the results written to the `.coverage` sqlite database to terminal, like

```
> pytest tests --cov -n 12
...

> coverage report
...
```

Comment: if you get the chance to reproduce and file a bug report...

Comment: It looks like a bug in `pytest-cov`, not in `coverage`.

Comment: _[rather off-topic, just for completeness, what I tried]_ When calling `coverage run -m pytest tests -n 12` I get `CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)`, while without `-n 12` it works. But _not_ using `pytest-xdist` is not an option for me.